# rails Active record sql injection

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-injection

can anybody explain why this is throwing exception

```
User.find_by_name("kotori", :select => "id, name FROM users; DROP TABLE users; --")

 User Load (0.0ms)   Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE users; -- FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`name` = 'kotori') LIMIT 1' at line 1: SELECT id, name FROM users; DROP TABLE users; -- FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`name` = 'kotori') LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE users; -- FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`name` = 'kotori')  LIMIT 1' at line 1: SELECT id, name FROM users; DROP TABLE users; -- FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`name` = 'kotori')  LIMIT 1

from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:324:in `execute'
from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:639:in `select'
from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all_without_query_cache'
from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:62:in `select_all'
from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql_without_default_slave'
from /gems/active_record_shards-2.7.0/lib/active_record_shards/default_slave_patches.rb:12:in `find_by_sql'
from /gems/active_record_shards-2.7.0/lib/active_record_shards/default_slave_patches.rb:93:in `on_slave_unless_tx'
from /gems/active_record_shards-2.7.0/lib/active_record_shards/default_slave_patches.rb:11:in `find_by_sql'
from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:1582:in `find_every_without_default_slave'
from /gems/active_record_shards-2.7.0/lib/active_record_shards/default_slave_patches.rb:12:in `find_every'
from /gems/active_record_shards-2.7.0/lib/active_record_shards/default_slave_patches.rb:93:in `on_slave_unless_tx'
from /gems/active_record_shards-2.7.0/lib/active_record_shards/default_slave_patches.rb:11:in `find_every'
from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:1539:in `find_initial'
from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:617:in `find'
from /gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:1918:in `find_by_name'
```

in [this](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/01/03/rails-sql-injection-vulnerability-hold-your-horses-here-are-the-facts/) article they say sql injection is possible i am not able to reproduce this what am i doing wrong?? any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Maybe you are using a rails version where the vulnerability was fixed

Comment: i am using rails 2.3.18

Comment: is bobby table attack possible in rails? which versions are vulnerable.

Comment: It was fixed in: 3.2.10, 3.1.9, 3.0.18

Comment: i am not not able to reproduce in any version of rails i tried 2.1.2 , 2.3.14 every where it is the same exception is it fixed across all the tags?? can anyone know the patch for this